# How can I use Logitech Options to lock my screen with my MX Ergo?

Tags: mouse, screen-lock

On Windows I'm used to locking my screen via a Logitech Mouse Gesture. Unfortunately, I cannot select "Lock Screen" in the menu on MacOS. Is there still another way to lock the screen?

Given that Logitech Options allows me to launch a specific app, is there an App that I can launch to lock the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Logitech Options, you can assign a keyboard sequence to a button.  For this example, I assigned the top button  on the side (the one highlighted in green) the shortcut to lock the screen <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

[image]

Now, when I press the button, it's as if I've pressed the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it natively, you don't need Logitech Options to do it for you.

System Prefs > Mission Control > Hot Corners...

You can pick a function for each corner & also define whether you need to be holding a Modifier key while you perform the action [safer for ones that would inconvenience you if done accidentally]

If you hold any Modifier[s] whilst selecting from the drop menu, it will apply it to the gesture.

[image]

Then just drag the cursor into the hot corner (optionally whilst holding your chosen modifier[s])

Comment: Part of the beauty of Logitech mouse gestures is that the mouse buttons work as modifier keys and thus the command that would create inconvenience when triggered automaticaly can be triggered without needing the keyboard. The amount of mouse travel that's involved is also less.

Comment: More than two years later… I see this comment & Allan's answer. The major downside of assigning something as 'hard' as lock screen to a single button is the number of times you'll do it accidentally, whilst pretty much 'wasting' a button for the rest of the time.